# Change a dataframe in matrix with 0 and 1 informations with R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, bioinformatics

I have a dataframe such as :

```
Cluster sequence_name
1       species1
1       species1
1       species2
1       species3
1       species3
1       gene1
1       gene2
2       species4
2       species5
2       spciess5
2       species3
2       gene3
2       gene4
```

and I would like to get a matrix with it such as :

```
           gene1  gene2 gene3 gene4
species5   0      0     1     1
species4   0      0     1     1
species1   1      1     0     0
species2   1      1     0     0
species3   1      1     1     1
```

where `1` means that for the `speciesX` the gene is present, and `0` means it is nos present. 
Present means that the `speciesX` is present in the `same cluster` than a `geneX`. For exemple, gene1 is present in the `cluster1` as the `species1, 2 and 3`. 
In contrary, `species5 and 4` are notre present in the `cluster1`.

As you can also see; there are several duplicates (in the same cluster, a species can be representated several times).
Thank you for your help.

The real data looks like:

```
cluster_names seq_names  
1             AP_000401.1  
1             NP_039001.1  
1             Canis_lupus  
1             Canis_familiaris
2             YP_0090909.1
2             Mustela_putorius
2             Mustela_furo
2             YP_0909200.1
```

....

```
...
```

AP and NP and other XX letters are genes 
and the Genus_specie the species

In response to Denis:

Here is a head of the real data:

```
cluster_names  seq_names
1   scf7180005155889:2745-3053(-):Drosophia_melanogaster
1   IDBA_scaffold_72878:85-225:292707-293006(+):Orussu_sp
1   scaffold_3615:40850-41320(-):Canis_lupus
1   scaffold_8697:754-1209(-):homo_sapiens
1   scf7180005155889:72-1908(-):homo_sapiens
1   YP_003969716.1
1   NP_003986717.1
2   scaffold_17536:2745-3053(-):Drosophia_melanogaster
2   scf7180005155889:2000-8900(-):Drosophia_melanogaster
2   scaffold_8697:754-1209(-):homo_sapiens
2   YP_003956764.1
2   YP_004894416.1
2   YP_008958968.1
```

and the output I should get is :

[image: output]

In respons to Denis:

```
> df <- read.table(text = "Cluster sequence_name
+ 1       :Drosophia_melanogaster
+                  1       scf7180005155889:2745-3053(-):Drosophila_melanogaster
+                  1       scf7180005155889:2745-3053(-):Orussu_sp
+                  1       scf7180005155889:2745-3053(-):Canis_lupus
+                  1       scf7180005155889:72-1908(-):Homo_sapiens
+                  1       scf7180005155889:2745-3053(-):Homo_sapiens
+                  1       YP_003970075.1
+                  1       YP_005070075.1
+                  2       scf7180005155889:72-1908(-):Drosophila_melanogaster
+                  2       scf7180005155889:72-1908(-):Drosophila_melanogaster
+                  2       scf7180005155889:72-1908(-):Homo_sapiens
+                  2       YP_039970075.1
+                  2       NP_003900075.1",header = T)
> df <- setDT(df)
> species <- df[grep("[0-9]+\\([+-]\\):[A-z ]+",sequence_name)]
> species[,sequence_name := str_extract(sequence_name,"(?<=[0-9]\\([+-]\\):)[A-z ]+")]
> genes <- df[grep("[0-9]+\\.1",sequence_name)]
> genes[,sequence_name :=sequence_name]
> plouf <- merge(genes,species,by = "Cluster",allow.cartesian=TRUE)
> result <- dcast(plouf,sequence_name.y~sequence_name.x,fun.aggregate = length)
Using 'sequence_name.y' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
> row.names(result)<-result$sequence_name.y
> result$sequence_name.y<- NULL
> result
   NP_003900075.1 YP_003970075.1 YP_005070075.1 YP_039970075.1
1:              0              1              1              0
2:              2              1              1              2
3:              1              2              2              1
4:              0              1              1              0
```

Comment: How do we know which row is a gene and which row is a species? I assume in real data they have different names?

Comment: by the way you have typos in species names...

Comment: Yes the real datas looks like:                                                                cluster_names seq_names
1 AP_000401.1
1 NP_039001.1                                                                                                          1 Canis_lupus
1 Canis_familiaris
...

Comment: We need to know how to differentiate between genes and species names. Please update your example to represent your "real" data.

Comment: Can genes be duplicate, i.e., gene1 can occur more than once?

Comment: No gene cannot be duplicated. I updated my post with some data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
df <- setDT(df)
```

I will use `data.table` here. So the idea is to create two data frame, one with the genes, one with the species

```
species <- df[grep("species",sequence_name)]
species[,sequence_name := str_extract(sequence_name,"(?<=:)[a-z0-9]+$")]
genes <- df[grep("gene",sequence_name)]

> species
   Cluster sequence_name
1:       1      species1
2:       1      species2
3:       1      species3
4:       2      species4
5:       2      species5
6:       2      species3
> genes
   Cluster sequence_name
1:       1         gene1
2:       1         gene2
3:       2         gene3
4:       2         gene4
```

You want to merge them together by cluster, with `allow.cartesian=TRUE` because your merging vector is not a single identifier for none of your data.frame:

```
plouf <- merge(genes,species,by = "Cluster",allow.cartesian=TRUE)

    Cluster sequence_name.x sequence_name.y
 1:       1           gene1        species1
 2:       1           gene1        species2
 3:       1           gene1        species3
 4:       1           gene2        species1
 5:       1           gene2        species2
 6:       1           gene2        species3
 7:       2           gene3        species4
 8:       2           gene3        species5
 9:       2           gene3        species3
10:       2           gene4        species4
11:       2           gene4        species5
12:       2           gene4        species3
```

Then, obtaining your result is just going to wide format while counting the number of occurence, which you can do with `dcast` here:

```
result <- dcast(plouf,sequence_name.y~sequence_name.x,fun.aggregate = length)


   sequence_name.y gene1 gene2 gene3 gene4
1:        species1     1     1     0     0
2:        species2     1     1     0     0
3:        species3     1     1     1     1
4:        species4     0     0     1     1
5:        species5     0     0     1     1
```

Et voilà. I let `dplyr` experienced users to propose the equivalent/improved solution with `dplyr`.

### The data :

```
df <- read.table(text = "Cluster sequence_name
1       Scaffold_1:species1
                 1       Scaffold_2:species2
                 1       Scaffold_3:species3
                 1       gene1
                 1       gene2
                 2       Scaffold_4:species4
                 2       Scaffold_5:species5
                 2       Scaffold_6:species3
                 2       gene3
                 2       gene4",header = T)
```

---

With the real data you show:

```
df <- read.table(text ="cluster_names  seq_names
                 1   scf7180005155889:2745-3053(-):Drosophia_melanogaster
                 1   scaffold_2484:292707-293006(+):Orussu_sp
                 1   scaffold_3615:40850-41320(-):Canis_lupus
                 1   scaffold_8697:754-1209(-):homo_sapiens
                 1   scf7180005155889:72-1908(-):homo_sapiens
                 1   YP_003969716.1
                 1   NP_003986717.1
                 2   scaffold_17536:2745-3053(-):Drosophia_melanogaster
                 2   scf7180005155889:2000-8900(-):Drosophia_melanogaster
                 2   scaffold_8697:754-1209(-):homo_sapiens
                 2   YP_003956764.1
                 2   YP_004894416.1
                 2   YP_008958968.1",header = T)
```

You should change the step of creating the two data table by:

```
species <- df[grep("[0-9]+\\([+-]\\):[A-z ]+",seq_names)]
species[,sequence_name := str_extract(seq_names,"(?<=[0-9]\\([+-]\\):)[A-z ]+")]
genes <- df[grep("[0-9]+\\.1",seq_names)]
genes[,sequence_name :=seq_names]
```

Here `"[0-9]+\\.1"` suppose that all genes finish with 1, and that there is no point in the species description. To extract the species info, I suppose that it always contain `(+):` or `(-)+` after numbers.

But that is a regex problem, and should be the matter of an other question if you have problem with it. Your question here was to find the way of shaping the data to obtain your result. I answered by giving you the steps working on the example data : creating the two genes and species data frame using regex, merging them and re-shaping them.

The rest works:

```
plouf <- merge(genes,species,by = "cluster_names",allow.cartesian=TRUE)
result <- dcast(plouf,sequence_name.y~sequence_name.x,fun.aggregate = length)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited my post, I have an issue when I creat the species dataframe.

Comment: I updated my post to show you how my data REAL look like and the output matrix. (But I can remove the `"scf..._X:X-X(-):"` part from myself but if you have a R code do to it it would be very helpfull.  Thank you for your help it is very clever. The answer of how to recognize gene from data is that genes have always a `YP_` or `NP_` at the begenning, and species have a structure such as : `scfnumber:numbernumber(+ or - ):Genus_species` and `scaffold_number:number-number(+ or -):Genus_species`

Comment: @darwin98 I proposed an edit, but will no further answer about specific problems due to the format of your data. It is not the subject of your initial question. Ask an other question for a `regex` problem if you continue having problem. Don't hesitate to accept if the answers suits you

Comment: it works like a charm thank you for your time !! I just edited my script because I obtain the count of all duplicates instead of just "1" if at least one species is in the same cluster than en gene. I should get 1 instead of 2 in my matrix. Do you know where is the issue in the code?

Comment: There isn't any issue, it is what the code is doing: counting the number of occurrence. I don't know what the `fun.agregate` should be to just have 0 or 1, but you could just do `result[,c(names(result)) := lapply(.SD,function(col){as.numeric(col > 0) }),.SDcols = c(names(result)) ]`

Comment: Ok thank you again for you help it was very helpfull.

Answer (score 3):

Using *tidyverse*:

```
# data
df1 <- read.table(text = "Cluster sequence_name
1       species1
                  1       species1
                  1       species2
                  1       species3
                  1       species3
                  1       gene1
                  1       gene2
                  2       species4
                  2       species5
                  2       species5
                  2       species3
                  2       gene3
                  2       gene4", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# so that we know which row is species
species <- paste("species", 1:5, sep = "")
#[1] "species1" "species2" "species3" "species4" "species5"

library(tidyverse)

res <- reduce(split(df1, df1$sequence_name %in% species), left_join, by = "Cluster") %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  spread(key = "sequence_name.x", value = "Cluster") %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric,  funs(as.numeric(!is.na(.))))

res
#   sequence_name.y gene1 gene2 gene3 gene4
# 1        species1     1     1     0     0
# 2        species2     1     1     0     0
# 3        species3     1     1     1     1
# 4        species4     0     0     1     1
# 5        species5     0     0     1     1
```